# Are there some default grid pattern textures in blender?

Tags: texturing, image

I'm looking for a texture like this one:

[image]

Or the grid on the ground here:

[image]

Are those already implemented in blender internal? Or else in Cycles ?

I searched for "grid textures", "color grid textures" (on google) to get the images and apply them as image textures but I didn't find them.

Is it possible to generate them procedurally (in python)?

Comment: See: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13453/241

Comment: See [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27411/2217) about the black and white type grid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three grid pattern textures, or checker patters in blender.

Two are accessible only from blender's [Image Editor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping/UV_Image_Editor) when making a new image.
[image]
Those are the *UV Grid* and *Color Grid*
[image] [image: Color Grid]

The other pattern is built in to cycles as the [Checker Texture](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/Textures#Checker_Texture).
[image]