# How do I create a texture displaying a 10cm grid

Tags: rendering, texturing

I'm new to this website so please forgive me if this is in the wrong place,

this is my last resort, I cannot find this picture texture and I would really want to use it, does anybody know where I can find it?
This is the texture, I cropped it from another Blender render:
[image]

Here is the reference to the image

Comment: Type a 'measure grid' or 'measure grid texture' in Google (example- http://www.floridatshirtsplus.com/images/grid.gif) or make your own in Photoshop- it's really easy and fast to do it.

Comment: If you download the file in question, the texture is included on the Textures folder.... It's called GRID-10cm.jpg.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it's not really about blender but about file on blendswap

Comment: If you change your question to "how do I create this texture" it would be a good question, but as it is, it is off topic. BSE is not a image searching site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [cegaton](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27411/last-resort-i-cannot-find-this-texture#comment41505_27411) pointed out, the texture you are looking for is bundled in the blend on blendswap. The file is listed as CC0, so I can freely post it here.
[image: grid image]

It is a simple image that you could easily create in blender with a grid rendered with freestyle, and a text object in the corner. Below is the blend file fully ready to render a grid like the picture above. (wait for the render to fully finish before the freestyle line show up.)

**[Blend File](https://github.com/David-Bates/blend-files/blob/master/grid.blend)** click the "View Raw" button to download.